# jQuery radio input .on('change') triggered twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, input

I have the following code: http://jsfiddle.net/0Lp4oqn6/

```
On <input type='radio' name='radio' class='radio' value='on'>
Off <input type='radio' name='radio' class='radio' value='off'>

$('.radio').on('change', function() {
    alert( $(this).val() )
}).trigger('change')
```

It's a simple set of 2 radio inputs and an event handler for when the radio input value changes. There is also a `.trigger('change')` in order to trigger the event handler to happen once when the page loads.

When the page loads, the event handler is triggered twice. The first alert will say `on` and the second alert will say `off`. But when I manually click the radio buttons, the change handler is not triggered twice.

Why is the event handler being triggered twice when using `.trigger('change')`? Why is the behavior different when doing it manually? What is the proper way to programmatically trigger the event handler without it happening twice?

Comment: 1. Why is the event handler being triggered twice when using `.trigger('change')`?
There is two radio button. so `$('.radio').trigger()` is called twice.

2. Why is the behavior different when doing it manually?
When you trigger manually it only called the event change not it triggers the change.

3. What is the proper way to programmatically trigger the event handler without it happening twice?

If you want to set the change in first radio button. trigger like `$('.radio').eq(0).trigger('change')`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The event will be triggered on each element in the collection regardless of their checked state. Two radios means two events triggered

It would probably be best to only trigger it if one of them is actually checked and only trigger on that particular one.

You can use `filter(':checked')` to target the checked one, if there is one

When you manually change a radio the change event is only triggered on a checked one also

```js
$('.radio').on('change', function() {
  console.log('Checked value =', $(this).val())
}).filter(':checked').trigger('change');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
On <input type='radio' name='radio' class='radio' value='on'> 
Off <input type='radio' name='radio' class='radio' value='off' checked>
```

Comment: This seems to be the best answer. Although I think it's weird that `.trigger()` would apply to both inputs but `.on('change'...` would only create a single event handler even though there are two inputs. Thanks

Comment: Single handler yes....but the listener is on all elements in collection. Is same as doing `$('.radio').each(function(){ $(this).change..... })`. The `each` is done internally by jQuery when you do `$(selector).method()`

Answer (score 2):

use `e.stopImmediatePropagation();`

Try:

```
$('.radio').on('change', function(e) {
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    alert( $(this).val() )
}).trigger('change')
```

Answer (score 2):

It's the chained `.trigger('change')` - just remove it.

since you need to call the `change` function on load, I would suggest

```
function onRadioChange() { ... }

$('.radio').on('change', onRadioChange);

onRadioChange();
```

Comment: But I need to programmatically trigger the event handler when the page loads. Why would I remove it?

Comment: the problem is that you're chaining onto the matches for `.radio`, i.e. both buttons

Answer (score 0):

On document load, the change triggers for .radio class. Since the radio class has 2 radio buttons it will trigger change for both of them as it identifies both with the same class.
While doing it manually the event os being triggered on the radio button on which you have made a click and hence the event is triggered only for that button.

Answer (score 0):

This can also work, using the `stopImmediatePropagation`:

```
$('.your_class_name').change(function(event) {
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    alert($(this).val());
});
```